# Exception from HRESULT: 0xFFFFFFF8

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sdk, fingerprint

I keep getting this error in my controller during verification of fingerprint. And I can't seem to understand why. I'm using digitalPersona SDK Fingerprint reader, asp.netc#. I already tried googling but with no success. T_T

This is my codes in my controller

```
    void verificationControl_OnComplete(object Control, DPFP.FeatureSet FeatureSet, ref DPFP.Gui.EventHandlerStatus EventHandlerStatus)
    {
        clearInfoBoxTimer.Stop();

        DateTime entryTime = DateTime.Now;

        DPFP.Verification.Verification ver = new DPFP.Verification.Verification();
        DPFP.Verification.Verification.Result res = new DPFP.Verification.Verification.Result();

        employee employees = null;
        foreach (fingerprint fingerPrint in this.db.fingerprints)
        {
            DPFP.Template template = new DPFP.Template();
            template.DeSerialize(fingerPrint.data);
            ver.Verify(FeatureSet, template, ref res); //I GETTING AN ERROR HERE
            if (res.Verified)
            {
                employees = fingerPrint.employee;
                break;
            }
        }
     }
```

Full Error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0xFFFFFFF8): Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0xFFFFFFF8
>          at DPFP.Verification.Verification.MC_verifyFeaturesEx(SafeHandle
>   mcContext, Int32 templateSize, Byte[] templatePt, Int32
>   featureSetSize, Byte[] featureSet, Int32 reserved0, IntPtr reserved1,
>   IntPtr reserved2, IntPtr reserved3, Double& achievedFar)
>          at DPFP.Verification.Verification.Verify(FeatureSet FeatureSet, Template Template, Int32 FARRequested)
>          at DPFP.Verification.Verification.Verify(FeatureSet FeatureSet, Template Template, Result& Result)
>          at Timee.BundyForm.verificationControl_OnComplete(Object Control, FeatureSet FeatureSet, EventHandlerStatus&
>   EventHandlerStatus) in
>   C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\Time\Timee\BundyForm.cs:line 79
>          at DPFP.Gui.Verification.VerificationControl.<>c_*DisplayClass2.b*_0()

Does anyone knows why I'm getting this error? or perhaps knows something about the error and share it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure about this but I think my error has something to do with the datatype that I use. I use previously binary(255) to insert a long binary fingerprint data in mysql. I think binary(255) is not enough to store the long binary value of fingerprint.In my previous server which is sql server, I use binary(1632) to store the fingerprint binary data. So I changed it to BLOB datatype. So now it doesn't get an error.

Answer (score 1):

Well ... I had that problem today, but the detail was that I was comparing the features with an '' in the database, i change the '' by a null value and voilà